# Magento 2: How to add Text Box in Admin Listing?

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, magento2.1.5

I need to add texbox in below code.

```
$this->addColumn(
                'qty', [
            'header' => __('Qty'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'qty',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
                ]
        );
```

So user can input quantity row wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->addColumn(
                'qty[]', [
            'header' => __('Qty'),
            'type' => 'input', // Change to Input
            'index' => 'qty',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
                ]
        );
```

Comment: Do you have document of types?